# NDK Integration with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm new in NDK .and try to setup Integration with NDk .But after research           through many sites ,i could not solved my problem. Here is build.gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
     model {
      android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    }

  android.ndk {
    moduleName "native"
   }

  defaultConfig.with {
    applicationId "app.com.jnitester"
    minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
    targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    buildConfigFields {
        create() {
            type = "int"
            name = "VALUE"
            value = "1"
        }
    }
}

/*   android.ndk {
    moduleName = "native"
}*/


android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
    }
}

android.productFlavors {
    create("flavor1") {
        applicationId "com.app"
    }
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jni {

            source {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}

my classpath is:
```

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'

we get error like that:

Error:(18, 0) No signature of method:     org.gradle.model.dsl.internal.NonTransformedModelDslBacking.applicationId() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [app.com.jnitester]
    Open File

when i put `buildTypes,productFlavours,sources` inside `android{}` then it gives Errors like that:

```
Error:(4, 1) A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
   > Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [23] on project ':app'.
```

may be this question be duplicate but we couldn't find the solution yet .
 Your help would save my time. Any Help would be appreciated in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

try adding '=' char. e.g.

compileSdkVersion 23

change to

compileSdkVersion = 23